# Facebook - Likes and comments not showing up in news feed; Photos tab is not visible to everyone

Tags: facebook, privacy, photos, photo-sharing, news-feed

My likes and comments are not showing up in my newsfeed (after days).  The Photos tab is not visible to everyone.

Here are my privacy settings:

> Account -> Privacy Settings ->
>   Connecting on Facebook - View Settings
>   -> "See your likes, activities and other connections" = "Everyone"
>
> Account -> Privacy Settings ->
>   Customize Settings -> "Posts by me"
>   "Default setting for posts, including
>   status updates and photos" -> Everyone
>
> Account -> Privacy Settings ->
>   Customize Settings -> "Edit privacy
>   settings for existing photo albums and
>   videos" -> Photo Albus -> Everyone
>
> Newsfeed -> Most Recent -> Edit
>   Options -> All of your friends and
>   pages -> Edit Options -> Hide posts
>   from >
>
> Apps (left hand column of Home
>   page) -> "To control how your friends
>   see your activity, click here" -> Info
>   accessible through your friends ->
>   [Boxes checked] "Bio,"  "Interested
>   in," "My photos," "My links," "My
>   notes," "Activities, interests, things
>   I like"

(Note that I did not select "status updates" in the Apps setting.  Facebook documentation says "status updates" are exclusively that - you used that named function to post an update - it's not likes, comments, photos, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to your News Feed (Top News), News Feed (Most Recent), or the Recent Activity on your profile?

I think that News Feed (Top News) only displays what Facebook considers to be most interesting to you, so I wouldn't expect your own likes/comments there.  The News Feed setting that you mentioned applies to the Most Recent setting.

News Feed (Most Recent) does not display individual stories for comments and likes on posts; you would only see them under the corresponding post, if it is expanded.  Are you saying that you expanded the likes/comments and you can see comments from other people but your comment is not there?  Sometimes it takes some time for it to show up although it shouldn't take days (unless it was deleted).

If you are referring to the Recent Activity on your profile, there is an additional setting for that that you didn't mention.  On your profile's Wall (not your News Feed), scroll to the bottom and click **Edit Options**.  If you have hidden any kinds of stories from your Recent Activity these will be listed and you can unhide any of them by clicking the **X** and then **Save**.
[image][image: Recent Activity options]

As for the Photos tab, that used to be a [known issue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9819/490) although the link to Facebook Help in that answer does not seem to work now.  I don't know if that means that it should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for helping.  I don't see "edit options" when I click on Profile (top right), or on Wall, near the top left, under the profile picture.  I put that text in the Firefox search box - there are no matches.  I found the old problem on the photos tab being a known problem - but I don't see any updates.  When my friends like a page, I see it on my news feed. When I like the same page, or other pages, they don't see it.  I am aware that you won't see your own likes on your own news feed.

Comment: To get to Edit Options you have to scroll to the bottom of your Wall page (and keep scrolling since it will add more).  I've added a screenshot.

Comment: Doesn't even apply any more. Facebook has changed, but this site's "helpline" hasn't reflected these changes. Out Of Date!